Java ENUM Generic Function
I have two ENUM with same keys but different keyValues as follows:
enum STUDENT_INFO {
    NAME("Student Name"),
    AGE("Age"),
    DOB("Date of Birth"),
    SEX("Sex"),
    LOCATION1("Hostel Info"),
    LOCATION2("Permanent Address"),
    ID("Institution ID"),
    INSTITUTE("Institution Name");

    private final String enumKey;
    STUDENT_INFO(String enumKey) {
        this.enumKey = enumKey;
    }
    public String getEnumKey() {
        return enumKey;
    }
}

enum PERSON_INFO {
    NAME("Person Name"),
    AGE("Age"),
    DOB("Date of Birth"),
    SEX("Sex"),
    LOCATION1("Present Address"),
    LOCATION2("Permanent Address"),
    ID("Person ID"),
    INSTITUTE("Job Name");

    private final String enumKey;
    PERSON_INFO(String enumKey) {
        this.enumKey = enumKey;
    }
    public String getEnumKey() {
        return enumKey;
    }
}

I want to Create a generic function (printGenericEnumInfo) to print anyone of those ENUM Keys.
class JavaTest {
    public static void printStudentEnumInfo() {
        System.out.println(STUDENT_INFO.NAME.getEnumKey());
        System.out.println(STUDENT_INFO.LOCATION1.getEnumKey());
        System.out.println(STUDENT_INFO.LOCATION2.getEnumKey());
    }

    // Generic Method to Print Enum Keys
    public static void printGenericEnumInfo(Enum<T> enumName) {
        System.out.println(enumName.NAME.getEnumKey());
        System.out.println(enumName.LOCATION1.getEnumKey());
        System.out.println(enumName.LOCATION2.getEnumKey());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Working perfectly
        JavaTest.printStudentEnumInfo();

        // How to implement this
        JavaTest.printGenericEnumInfo(STUDENT_INFO);
        JavaTest.printGenericEnumInfo(PERSON_INFO);
    }
}

Can you help me how to do this ?
Demo Code: tutorialspoint_JavaCompiler

Do you just want to print the keys of NAME, LOCATION1 and LOCATION2 specifically?

no all keys @Sweeper. Actually all three keys have different value that's why I have highlighted those. It should be print like: enumName.ENUM_KEY.getEnumKey()

tutorialspoint_JavaCompiler_Generic

Change Enum keys little bit according to my requirements and this my solution: http://tpcg.io/_VTDUJ3. Thanks to @SharadPaul for sharing the valuable information

@SharadPaul I have update solution above with help of you & Sweeper. Do you have any other way  to print Enum keys?

No it's fine ...

The two enums should both implement such an interface:
interface HasEnumKey {
    String getEnumKey();
}

enum STUDENT_INFO implements HasEnumKey { ... }
enum PERSON_INFO implements HasEnumKey { ... }

Then the method can take a Class<T> representing the enum class. Constrain T to be an enum and to implement HasEnumKey,
static <T extends Enum<T> & HasEnumKey> void printGenericEnumInfo(Class<T> enumClass) {
    for (T value: enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        System.out.println(value.getEnumKey());
    }
}

Usage:
printGenericEnumInfo(STUDENT_INFO.class);


Actually I want to use it to parse/Update some JSON Object with in printGenericEnumInfo(). So, can we get enum keys as follows:  enumClass.NAME.getEnumKey(). Actually I don't want to use forloop to print a enum key value @Sweeper

@ArtBindu It is unclear what you want to do. What is enumClass.NAME.getEnumKey() supposed to mean?

actually I don't want to use forloop to print the enum keys within function: printGenericEnumInfo(). I want to print enum key values following way: enumClass.KEY_NAME.getEnumKey() @Sweeper

@ArtBindu Do you realise you just repeated basically the same thing that I didn't understand? Do you mean you want to get the enum value with a given name? That'd be Enum.valueOf(enumClass, "NAME").getEnumKey(). You can replace NAME with AGE, DOB, SEX etc.
